# Android IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I know there are several questions like this one, but all of them seem to have a different approach to solve the problem and none have solved mine.

I have my main activity working just fine, loading the db and populating the listview. Then I call a second activity and the problem shows up when I try to load the listview.

I have tried using `start/stop managingcursor(cursor)` even though it is deprecated, but it didn't fix the problem. Also I tried cloasing the cursor and db in my main activity before firing the next one but that didn't help either.

Both classes extend from ListActivity and follow the same sequence:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    //Open db in writing mode
    MySQLiteHelper.init(this);
    MySQLiteHelper tpdbh =
        new MySQLiteHelper(this, "DB", null, 1);


    SQLiteDatabase db = tpdbh.getWritableDatabase();

    checkLocationAndDownloadData(); //this fires a Asynctask that calls method parseNearbyBranches shown bellow

   //I load the data to the ListView in the postExecute method of the asynctask by calling:
    /*
    Cursor cursor = MysSQLiteHelper.getBranchesNames();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, fields, new int[] { R.id.item_text },0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    */

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
            int position, long id) {

         // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
         Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

       // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
       String branch_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("branch_id"));

           cursor.close();

        openNextActivity(Integer.parseInt(branch_id));
        }
      });
}
```

//In another file:

```
private void parseNearbyBranches(JSONObject jo) throws JSONException
{
 if (   jo.has(jsonTitle) && 
            jo.has("company_id") &&
            jo.has("id")
    ) {
        String branch = jo.getString(jsonTitle);


            MySQLiteHelper tpdbh = MySQLiteHelper.instance;
            SQLiteDatabase db = tpdbh.getWritableDatabase();

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Branches (branch_id, name, company_id) " +
                    "VALUES ('" +jo.getInt("id")+"', '" + branch +"', '" +jo.getInt("company_id")+"' )");

            db.close(); //no difference is I comment or uncomment this line

    }
}
```

In MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
public static Cursor getBranchesNames() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "branch_id", "name", "company_id" };
        Cursor c = getReadDb().query(branchesTable, columns, null, null, null, null,
                null);            
        return c;
    }
```

My other activity does basically the same:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_branch_surveys);

    //Read branch data from DB
        int companyID = -1;
        MySQLiteHelper.init(this);          

        String [] columns = new String [] {"company_id"};
        String [] args = {Integer.toString(branchID)};
        Cursor c = MySQLiteHelper.getReadDb().query(MySQLiteHelper.branchesTable, columns, "branch_id=?", args, null, null, null); //THIS QUERY WORKS JUST FINE

        if (c.moveToFirst())
            companyID = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0));
        c.close();

        if( companyID != -1)
        {
            new DownloadTask().execute(Integer.toString(companyID) );
//where the Async task calls something just like NearByBranches shown above(but with different  objects of course)
//And the postExecute sets the listView:
/*  cursor = MySQLiteHelper.getAll();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.row, cursor, fields, new int[] { R.id.item_text },0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);  
*/
        }

    }
}
```

In MySQLiteHelper.java:

```
public static Cursor getAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id","title", "points" };

//********IT IS IN THIS LINE WHERE I GET THE ERROR:********************
    Cursor c = getReadDb().query(theTable, columns, null, null, null, null,
            null);

    return c;
}

  public static SQLiteDatabase getReadDb() {
        if (null == db) {
            db = instance.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        return db;
    }
```

I hope you can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: What is `getReadDb()`?  I assume it's quite simple.

Comment: I have updated the question with the 'getReadDb()' method. Basically is 'instance.getReadableDatabase();' of the sqlitedatabase

Comment: Thought so, but wanted to be sure. Do you call `db.close()` anywhere in that class? Or do you save the reference to `database = getReadDb()` and call `database.close()`?

Comment: Not in that class. I call db.close() in parseNearbyBranches() and in the similar method I call in the new activity

Comment: I feel stupid now.. I just tried commenting the db.close in the similar method of parseNeabyBranches and the problem was solved. Yet I dont get the same error having db.close() in parseNearbyBranches(), can you explain me why? (please do so as an answer so I can mark it as solved)

Comment: There is no reason to feel dumb, you simply needed a second set of eyes to see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just tried commenting the db.close in the similar method of parseNeabyBranches and the problem was solved. Yet I dont get the same error having db.close() in parseNearbyBranches(), can you explain me why?

In `parseNearbyBranches()` you create a separate SQLiteDatabase object with:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = tpdbh.getWritableDatabase();
```

Since this is a different object than the one returned by `getReadDb()`, you can (and should) close it.  The basic rule is each time you call `getWritableDatabase()` and `getReadableDatable()` you must have a matching `close()` statement.

Comment: I masked is as solved, although I am also creating a new SQLiteDatabase in the other similar too. It is really the same as parseNearbyBranches but with different JSON objects and a different query.

Comment: Hmm, is the code in your question?  I would like to see both of them, perhaps it is the way you create your MySQLHelper... it looks like you are trying to use one instance for all classes.

Comment: Here is the code of the other method: http://pastie.org/7328674

Comment: That is strange, I don't see anything obvious to explain the difference...  I'm glad we solved the error through.